# iPhone, how to capture when a search bar is empty and has text?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisearchbar

I need to disabled a button when theres no text in the search bar and enable the button when there is text in it.

I presume there must be an event or a way to detect the status of the text in the search bar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would utilize the UISearchBarDelegate class and implement the textDidChange method ([UISearchBarDelegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate)).

You can use this to "detect" changes to the search field and change the enable state of the button as the user edits the contents of the search bar.